# Loopback.io backup server and server to server replication

Tags: rest, replication, loopbackjs

I am thinking of adopting Loopback.io to create a REST API. I may need the following approach: an inTERnet server (run by me) to which clients connect, plus a fallback inTRAnet server to which clients connect only in case the internet connection is down. This secondary fallback server should then replicate data on the main server when the internet connection is up and running again. As clients are on the same inTRAnet they should be able to switch automatically to the fallback server. Is this possible as an idea and if so, what do you recommend i start digging into?

Thank you all!

Matteo

Answer (score 1):

Simon from my other account. I believe what you want is possible as you can use whatever client side technology you want with LoopBack. As for easy solutions, I'm not familiar enough with Cordova to give any insight there.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible, but I suggest going through the [getting started tutorial](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Getting+started+with+LoopBack) first. You'd probably create two application servers and have another proxy in front to route the requests to server a or b based a heartbeat from the main server. You would have to code all the logic and set up the infrastructure yourself though.

Comment: Thanks for clarification Simon - much appreciated. I have read a bit about Loopback and I like the approach, but have not gone into the nitty gritty details yet. So I assume there is no easy way to implement this on the client (i.e. without the proxy), assuming for instance it is a JS web application that i can then package in a Cordova-like fashion?